# Save a file to a USB with Chrome API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome app with `"usb"` permission and I want to create a file "notes.txt" in USB mass storage. When he finished and press "save to USB" button.

I tried to use chrome.usb.bulkTransfer, but it just ends with

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running usb.bulkTransfer: Transfer failed.
```

Is possible to save a file to a USB mass storage with Chrome API, without the direct input from user?

Comment: did you find a way?

Comment: if i remember correctly, the marked answer worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding saving a file to a USB mass storage without the direct input from user, try using [`chrome.usb.controlTransfer(connectionHandle, transferInfo, transferCallback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb#control_transfers) which is generally used to send or receive configurations or command parameters to a USB device. The controlTransfer method always sends to/reads from endpoint 0, and no claimInterface is required.

And since [`requestAccess`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb#method-requestAccess) is now deprecated, operation is now implicitly performed as part of [`openDevice`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb#method-openDevice) and this function will return true on all platforms.